# ArrayFormula Trouble pulling data for just a year or just last 15 days No understanding how to do

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Google sheet to see my problem

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e3sjPNDJ3crJVQIn9L-lKllXP0wvc9NC22cnjxCveEs/edit?usp=sharing

See separate tab (help)
See all Yellow Boxes........they have the formula that I want but they do not have the restriction of time.

see   L46 based on the last X amount of trades (15)
see   S10  based on data from the year (2020)
( I want to be able to type different years and day to have calculations.

I try and copy what I have and add years to it but always get a error

anyway you can fill out yellow boxes and I can then copy and modify them as I need?

Would be greatly appreciated I must have 4 hours in just r20 with error

=ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(F29:F38,">0",YEAR(P29:P45),S10)+COUNTIF(YEAR('Sold Stocks'!K2:K,”>0”),S10))

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se].  See [ask]. Links can be helpful but questions should include everything needed to answer. [Edit] your question to include sample data and your expected result.  Convert copied cells/tables from Sheets to [proper markdown format](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables). Tools like the [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) can make this easier.  Include relevant formulas describing what did/didn't work including any errors you encountered.